# CORS on POST using res.redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

This code worked as expected

```
app.get('/:phonenum', (req, res) => {
    var source = req.header('user-agent');
    var ua = useragent.parse(source);

    if (ua.isDesktop) {
        res.status(308).redirect(`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+${req.params.phonenum}`);
    }
})
```

But I try to fire an ajax request to another route, instead of GET I used POST

```
app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    var source = req.header('user-agent');
    var ua = useragent.parse(source);

    if (ua.isDesktop) {
        res.status(308).redirect(`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+${req.body.phone}&text=${req.body.msg}`);
    }
})
```

I got this error in chrome console.

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: lack of CORS headers seems to be the issue

Comment: This is a cross origin request error you can find details in here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Comment: @JaromandaX you mean by ajax's problem? what header do I need?

Comment: @JaromandaX what's wrong with my ajax code? http://pastebin.com/Ls7N1pNS

Comment: @selftaught91 why the GET is ok above?

Comment: the permanent redirect 308 status is different for a start

Comment: @JennyMok - `what's wrong with my ajax code?` I didn't say there was anything wrong with code that you haven't put in the question

Comment: @JennyMok you are firing GET request from ajax code or directly from browser

Comment: @selftaught91 what do you mean? I did not, it's POST

Comment: @selftaught91 http://pastebin.com/Ls7N1pNS. For the GET yes I'm hitting it directly from the browser.